# How many Menoros were there by the Simchas Bais HaShoeva

Tags: beis-hamikdash, sukkah, masechet-sukkah

The [Mishna Succah 51A](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.51a.16?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says:

> מְנוֹרוֹת שֶׁל זָהָב הָיוּ שָׁם, וְאַרְבָּעָה סְפָלִים שֶׁל זָהָב בְּרָאשֵׁיהֶם, וְאַרְבָּעָה סוּלָּמוֹת לְכׇל אֶחָד וְאֶחָד,

So we know that each Menorah had 4 cups on top. Is there any source that says how many Menoros there were or was it random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maharil ([Hilchos Sukkos](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14721#p=103)) is quoted as saying that there were four menoros. However, Amudei Yerushalayim (on [Yerushalmi Sukkah 5:2](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14138#p=306)) points out that there doesn't seem to be a source for that. (Various Acharonim often point out inaccuracies in Minhagei Maharil which they attribute to misunderstandings by the talmid who compiled it, R' Zalman of St. Goar, so this might just be another one of those.)

Pnei Moshe on the Yerushalmi there just says that there were "at least" two, and [Aruch Laner](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14414#p=206) to (Bavli) Sukkah 52b also understands the Yerushalmi to be saying that there were two menoros.